# Bean with scope "Request" with Task Scheduling (ThreadPoolTaskScheduler)

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

Need to call a bean with scope type "request" from Task Scheduler. I know this type of method runs in it's own thread and is not aware of the application context.

Can I get some feedback on any other alternative approaches that will enable  me to define a bean with a scope "request" inside a a method that should be invoked periodically?

Bean "ConnectionRepository" in the following method depends on another Bean that has a Scope "Request", which causes `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found` exception

OauthRefreshTask Class

```
    public class OauthRefreshTask implements Runnable, ApplicationContextAware{

        private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
            beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ConnectionRepository connectionRepository = beanFactory.getBean(ConnectionRepository.class);
                ...
}
    }
```

Controller Class

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private ApplicationContext appContext;
    @Inject
    public HomeController(ApplicationContext appContext) {
        this.appContext = appContext;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(HttpServletRequest request,Principal currentUser, Model model) {     
        try {
            task();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "home";
    }

    private void task() throws SchedulerException{
        OauthRefreshTask oauthRefreshTask = new OauthRefreshTask();
        oauthRefreshTask.setApplicationContext(appContext);     
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
        long timer = 1000;
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new OauthRefreshTask(), new Date(), timer);
    }
```

StackTrace

```
ERROR: org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.social.sample.account.OauthRefreshTask.run(OauthRefreshTask.java:26)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
```

Comment: It will simply never work. When the scheduled/async thread executes there is no more request scope and hence no more request scoped objects. It simply will not and cannot work with request scoped objects.

Comment: There is no request during the execution and thus no request scope. It will only work if you pass the values you need to another object or directly in the context map for execution. Request scope simply won't work.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue a few years ago. We fixed it by refactoring the application. We've created a custom context-object which is passed to the services and repos.

That context was mapped from request and session attributes when coming from the webapp. And it was created with a factory method when coming from the scheduled task.

Maybe this is not the most correct solution, but it worked for us. So maybe you can consider a similar refactoring.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    public void do(MyContext context) {
        // Do stuff with values from the context
    }
}


public class MyTask {

    @Autowired MyService myService;

    public void doSomething() {
        MyContext context = new MyContext("defaultRequestValue");
        myService.do(context);
    }
}


@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired MyService myService;

    public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        MyContext context = new MyContext(request.getParameter("theParam"));
        myService.do(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: @StefannNeyts Do you have an example?